# NSArray handled as NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, json

I am doing an HTTP call to my web server via objective-c app. The server returned json usually looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "surname": "test",
}
```

but sometimes, when I am requesting a list of something, I get the JSON like this:

```
[
  { "name": "test" },
  { "name": "test" },
]
```

Now, I am handling the returned object as NSDictionary this way:

```
NSDictionary *results = [http doRequestWithData:@{ @"tag": @"whatever" } atUrl:@"/search"]
NSLog(@"%@", results);
```

I have omitted the implementation of doRequestWithData for simplicity, because the interesting  part of it is that when I do an NSLog of data, I get the following:

```
(
        {
        "_id" = 5353c332339a5ea32e000008;
        content = "i am the first search result";
    },
        {
        "_id" = 5353c32b339a5ea32e000007;
        content = "I am the second";
    },
        {
        "_id" = 5353c31c339a5ea32e000006;
        content = "third";
    },
)
```

Can anyone explain how this can happen? The returned data is an NSDictionary, but from the console it seems just like an array, as I cannot see the keys!

---

UPDATE: I am using NSJSONSerialization in my http class to serialize the object. The docs say it may return either a dict or an array based on the data. but the problem is that I am clearly defining it as NSDictionary! Shouldn't this at least throw and error?
This is what I am using in my http class to define the returned nsdictionary:

```
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
return responseDict;
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the NSJSONSerialization is returning that data of class NSDicationary? `NSLog(@"%@", [data class]);`

Comment: Alright, it says __NSCFArray. That explains a lot but I still don't get why it works so flawlessly? The type is clearly defined as NSDictionary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Java (and similar languages), there is no runtime type checking in Obj-C.

If your method returns a `NSArray` and you store it into a `NSDictionary`, it's not a problem for Obj-C. Until you try to call a method which is not defined for `NSArray` (e.g. `objectForKey:`).

Usually, such problems should be cought at compile time, however

`+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:...]` returns an `id` (it can return either `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`) and `id` is compatible with any type.

Comment: do you reckon that it would then be better to return an object of type id then? rather than either array or dict

Comment: @user3060636 If both are possible return values for you, then `id` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to do your own type checking on returned value using `isKindOfClass:`.

```
NSData *data = ...;

NSError *__autoreleasing jsonError;
NSDictionary *dictionary = data ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError] : nil;

if (jsonError || ![dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    dictionary = nil;
```

You may want to do more handling than this, but this at least ensures you'll never access the wrong object type.